# Avoid implementing unused Listener methods

Tags: java, android, inheritance, listener

I'm developing an Android app, and used [this](http://blog.chrisblunt.com/android-map-view-double-taps-and-overlay-markers/) tutorial to achieve catching double tap events on my map. But I think is a more general problem. So, to get notified about specific events, I have to implement lot of listeners. These have plentiful of methods I won't use ever, so these are just "polluting" my code. Yes, I could use a listener adapter class, but i have to inherit from an other superclass, too, and multiple inheritance is not available in Java, unfortunately. Also, I cannot use delegation in this case, because my Activity class have to be the listener, too (at least I think).
So, is there any way in Java, to implement the used methods, and get rid of the others, somehow?

This is the example code what is describing the problem:

```
// ...

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener, OnGestureListener, OnDoubleTapListener {

    // ... my methods

    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        // actually this method is used by me only
    }

    // ... lots of other implemented listener methods what I do not use
}
```

Comment: Now i know that [AndroidAnnotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations) can help this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to rethink the design a bit.

There is clearly a need for your app to respond to various events, those events are generated by mechanism requiring different listeners, but you care only about subset of triggers.

What I would do is to implement MyAppEventTriggerQueue (it can use 
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html internally).

1. The object will have to have a worker thread that would listen on the queue changes and trigger YOUR custom call backs.
2. All the different listeners like MapActivity and SimpleGestureListener will populate the shared queue to which your MyAppEventTriggerQueue will respond by firing your custom events.

That way you are untying your self from the various interfaces and implementations, abstracting out everything except the events you need.

This is a bit more work, but it ultimately should be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2):

No. Once an interface is implemented, all its methods must be overridden.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with **Java 8** you can use ***default*** to effectively ignore unused/unwanted methods.

Here is an example that extends OnDoubleTapListener to only care about the onDoubleTap() method

```
interface OnDoubleTapOnlyListener extends GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener
{
    default boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) { return false; }

    boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e);

    default boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) { return false; }
}
```

And then you can just implement onDoubleTap and the others will be ignored.

**Unfortunately**, Android doesn't support Java 8 out of the box yet.
It is not impossible however, you can use Java 8 via Retrolambda https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda

Answer (score 0):

You can use abstract class :

```
 abstract  class DoubleTapListener implements   GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    abstract public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e);

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }


}
public class MainActivity extends DoubleTapListener{

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```